# UITextField has bottom border of tintColor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, interface-builder

I'm developing an app for a customer that is only used by a small company. This app has a login screen with two text inputs for username and password.

Specs:

- Xcode v11.3.1
- iPod touch iOS 13.3.1
- Swift 5

The user interface was built using the Interface Builder of Xcode. I set the border style of both `UITextField`s to `.roundedRect` and they look fine in Interface Builder:

[image: interface builder screenshot]

But as soon as I'm testing the app on my iPod touch the `UITextField`s have an annoying bottom border (or bottom line) of the tint color of the text field:

[image: ipod screenshot]

The lines are red because I've set the tint color of the text fields to red. The only solution (that is clearly not the best one) is to set the tint color to `UIColor.clear` for both text fields. Then the lines are disappearing. But then the blinking cursor of the text fields are also invisible while editing the text.

I tried a lot of different things like setting the border color of the layer (`textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor`) but nothing worked out so far.

I also searched the web for similar problems, but it seems that I'm pretty alone with this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it a standard UITextField or a custom one? Are you sure that there is not an extenison that add that beheviour in your project? Maybe a UIView extension

Comment: I'm so dumb. Thank you, that was exactly the problem! I thought it was a standard UITextField but it was actually a custom one. Thanks!

Comment: I think that is not a border of your textfield or may be bottom border is setting up from other block of code, show your code.